# VBA code to take all documents in a folder and make landscape, alter font size, fit table contents to window

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm having an issue with some VBA code.  I'd like to take all files in a directory, open them, convert their orientation to landscape, then change table contents to 'fittowindow', change font size to 9, then save and close the file and move on to the next file in the directory.  Here is my sample code: 
Option Explicit

```
Public Sub tablechanger()

Dim FS As New FileSystemObject
Dim FSfolder As Folder
Dim MyFile As File
Dim mydoc As Document
Dim sFolderPath As String
Dim Table As Table
    sFolderPath = "//network/location/"
    Set FSfolder = FS.GetFolder(sFolderPath)
    For Each MyFile In FSfolder.Files
           If Right(MyFile.Name, 3) = "rtf" And MyFile.Name <> ThisDocument.Name Then
               Set mydoc = Application.Documents.Open(MyFile.Path)
                   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                    ActiveDocument.PageSetup.Orientation = wdOrientLandscape
                   ActiveDocument.Find.Font.Size = 9
                   ActiveDocument.Tables(1).AutoFitBehavior wdAutoFitWindow
                   mydoc.SaveAs FileName:=Left(MyFile.Path, (InStrRev(MyFile.Path, ".", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1)), FileFormat:=wdFormatRTF
                   mydoc.Close savechanges:=True
               Application.DisplayAlerts = True
          End If
     Next
    End
    End Sub
```

Right now, the program gets as far as opening each file, and then stops doing anything.  Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'stops doing anything'? or do you get an error? I get error at 'ActiveDocument.Find.Font.Size = 9'.

Regardless, there is no Find on a Document object. You need to use `Selection` or `Range` to do a find. However, if all you want is to change the font for the entire document, just select the text and set the `Font` property to the desired size:

```
Selection.Font.Size = 18
```

Also - just in case this is run on a document which does NOT have any tables, wrap the table operation with a check:

```
If ActiveDocument.Tables.Count <> 0 Then
   ActiveDocument.Tables(1).AutoFitBehavior wdAutoFitWindow
End If
```

So here:

```
Public Sub tablechanger()

    Const FONT_SIZE_TO_CHANGE_TO As Integer = 18

    Dim FS As New FileSystemObject
    Dim FSfolder As Folder
    Dim MyFile As File
    Dim mydoc As Document
    Dim sFolderPath As String
    Dim Table As Table
        sFolderPath = "//network/location/"
        Set FSfolder = FS.GetFolder(sFolderPath)
        For Each MyFile In FSfolder.Files
               If Right(MyFile.Name, 3) = "rtf" And MyFile.Name <> ThisDocument.Name Then
                   Set mydoc = Application.Documents.Open(MyFile.Path)
                       Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                       ActiveDocument.PageSetup.Orientation = wdOrientLandscape

                       ActiveDocument.Select
                       Selection.Font.Size = FONT_SIZE_TO_CHANGE_TO

                       If ActiveDocument.Tables.Count <> 0 Then
                           ActiveDocument.Tables(1).AutoFitBehavior wdAutoFitWindow
                       End If
                       mydoc.SaveAs FileName:=Left(MyFile.Path, (InStrRev(MyFile.Path, ".", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1)), FileFormat:=wdFormatRTF
                       mydoc.Close savechanges:=True
                   Application.DisplayAlerts = True
              End If
         Next
        End
End Sub
```